# Allow only the users with the access code to browse the website

Tags: 7, users

I am building my site on Drupal 7.

I want to restrict the usage of my website only to certain people who I have sent the access code to. I don't want to put my website into maintenance mode because I want those users to fully use my site (including registration form etc.).

So how can I build a page with a simple form where users will enter the access code and then get allowed to enter the website? And also whenever somebody types in another URL in the website without actually entering the access code first, they must be redirected to the security page to enter the code; then they will be allowed to proceed to that URL they wanted to go to.

I would prefer to be able to remember their sessions and if the user has a session on the website (such that they have entered the code before) they shouldn't be sent to the security page the second time (until their session time ends maybe?).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hello, we're facing the exact same scenario. Could you please share the module you're talking about ? I barely know basic php notions so i don't really know how to create the custom form that should be placed within the block.
 I hope you'll be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create a page, and include the User Login as a block on that page. Theme as desired. You can also set this as a Front page in the system settings if you like.
- alternatively, create a customised user login, whereby the password is populated as part of a custom submit function of the form. Then you would use a *Code* as the user name, and the password would be automatically assigned. The question is too broad to detail how this would be accomplished. Look into the forms API and building forms with customised submit functionality.
- get [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan). It has a setting to redirect users to a specified page on access denied
- in permission, for Anonymous Role, uncheck ALL items. This will essentially disallow anonymous user to do anything, or view any content, which should then be redirected to the login page by logintoboggan

Keep in mind that this method is prone to major security breaches by bots. They WILL randomly guess the code and gain access to the site, which is why two fields are required in standard practice (email/user, password)

**EDIT FOR OP**

**I solved it by a custom module. I cant answer my own question due do low reputation so accepting yours as an answer and writing a comment. I created a block, which contains a custom form. This form redirects to home page if the access code is correct and also sets TRUE on $_SESSION['access_code']. And then I created a page and embedded the block In a custom Rule, I redirect user to the access page if $_SESSION['access_code'] is not TRUE and if the user is anonymous whatever the URL it is. So user always redirected to that page, unless they have entered the code before, or a logged in user.**

Comment: THanks for the answer Geoff but this is not the functionality my client desires. Users shouldn't be forced to create account to be able to browse, but they just need an "access code" which I will provide to them. Entering this access code will bypass the security page and the website will be available as a whole

Comment: Any helps or comments on this potential solution?: Create a custom form on a custom page (e.g mysite.com/mypage) then redirect all Anonymous users without PHP session to that page. When entered the correct access code, create a PHP session (not a drupal account) and redirect user to homepage. When they close the browser, obviously the session is lost. If they had registered, they wont see that security page again; if still anonymous, again they will be sent to security page to enter the code

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer again but this is not the desired effect I want to have. However, really good advice about the bots. I am trying to implement my strategy I mentioned in my above content. Will get back here and update the post if I can solve it

Comment: the Admins rejected your edit :) so I added it myself

Comment: @Geoff ... Please review my "extra" answer, as an attempt to get this OP-er edit "cleaned" up ... If this would cause  your answer to get unaccepted, then please notify me about that via an extra comment. In that case, and after you remove the "edit for OP"-part, rest assured of "my" +1 then, ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a module called Shield

https://www.drupal.org/project/shield

PHP Authentication shield. It creates a simple shield for the site with Apache authentication. It hides the sites, if the user does not know a simple username/password. It handles Drupal as a "walled garden".

I don't know if it will 'remember the session' but I believe it can help with the other part of you request

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer (solution) that [Shamil.F](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/33462/shamil-f) came up with ...

- This question can be solved by a custom module.
- I created a block, which contains a custom form.
- This form redirects to home page if the access code is correct and also sets TRUE on $_SESSION['access_code'].
- Then I created a page and embedded the block in a custom Rule: I redirect user to the access page if $_SESSION['access_code'] is not TRUE and if the user is anonymous whatever the URL it is.
- So user is always redirected to that page, unless they have entered the code before, or a logged in user.

PS: The comment like "*I cant answer my own question due do low reputation so accepting yours as an answer and writing a comment.*" seems a bit bizarre to me. Which is why I moved it (with some reformatting) to a separated answer.

I don't "expect" any upvotes for doing so, since I mostly posted this extra answer to have it posted as such (an an extra answer). At the risk that the OPer is now going to "change" the accepted answer to this answer ... And even at the risk of this answer being downvoted and/or deleted.

Oh well, so be it, I just wanted to help "clean up" the (pseudo-accepted) answer ... For any other user ever looking at this question, and answer(s).